# Query for getting real name

Tags: mysql

My problem is that I want to get the real name given a **name**(can be an alias or not). It will return the real name.

My table columns have: `name_id` `name` `alias_id` and etc. Where adding an alias is the same as adding a name but `alias_id` set to `name_id` of its real name. Adding a real name just sets alias_id to 0.

I tried:

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl_name
WHERE
    (alias_id <> 0 AND name = input_name) or name = input_name;
```

But it returns the alias_name. Thanks

**EDIT:** 
I created a sqlfiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72b432/2

Comment: `(alias_id <> 0 AND name = input_name) or name = input_name;` is the same as `name = input_name`. because of the `or`.

Comment: @JoshuaK so how do i select real name when `alias_id > 0`?

Comment: Can you show some sample data here?  You only have one `name` column and it is not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: the value of the `alias_id` field is not 100% clear, if it's a real name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join self:

```
select 
  t1.name 
from 
  tbl_name t1 
  left join tbl_name t2 on t1.name_id = t2.alias_id 
where 
  t1.alias_id = 0 
  and (
    t1.name = input_name 
    or t2.name = input_name
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the realname to a given real name or alias can be achieved by searching for the record with the given * name and use this as subquery :

The expression to find the record with the given name:

```
SELECT alias_id FROM tbl_name WHERE name = input_name;
```

this returns the record id of the record with the real name, so you have to

```
SELECT t1.name FROM tbl_name t1 WHERE t1.name_id = (
  SELECT t2.alias_id FROM tbl_name t2 WHERE t2.name = input_name
) or (t1.name = input_name AND t1.alias_id = 0);
```

Comment: this returns 2 columns but thanks. i know what to do now.

Comment: @just_a_simple_guy should work now. Thanks for pointing that out.